# increment value in dictionary based on key in another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-2.x

I have a `masterDict` dictionary with keys "1" through "8" with values set to `0`

```
{'1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 0, '5': 0, '6': 0, '7': 0, '8': 0}
```

I also have `anotherDict` that i'm using to find the key containing a value closest to another value (i'm doing this multiple times with different values).

An example of one of those other values would be `value1 = 900`

An example of `anotherDict` would be:

```
{'1': 74, '2': 938, '3': 28, '4': 10, '5': 100, '6': 33, '7': 45, '8': 99}
```

The code i'm using to find the value closest to `value1` in `anotherDict` is:

```
closestValue1 = key, value = min(anotherDict.items(), key=lambda (_, v): abs(v - value1))
```

In this case, `closestValue1` returns:

```
{'2': 938}
```

How do I take this and increment the key `2` value in `masterDict` by 1?

So, `masterDict` would then contain:

```
{'1': 0, '2': 1, '3': 0, '4': 0, '5': 0, '6':0, '7':0, '8': 0}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
master_dict = {'1': 0, '2': 0, '3': 0, '4': 0, '5': 0, '6': 0, '7': 0, '8': 0}
another_dict = {'1': 74, '2': 938, '3': 28, '4': 10, '5': 100, '6': 33, '7': 45, '8': 99}
target_val = 900
target_key, _ = min(another_dict.items(), key=lambda x: abs(target_value-x[1])) 
master_dict[target_key]+=1
print (master_dict)
```

Comment: Dear lord, I was hoping it wasn't going to be that easy, thank you though!